# angular 2 http get not resulting in any activity

Tags: angular

I have the following file, expanded from the file provided https://angular.io/guide/quickstart, that makes a get request. The problem is that under the networking tab in my browser, I don't see the network call being made to google. Why is it so?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private http:Http) {
        http.get('https://www.google.com');
        alert('hi');
    }
}
```

Comment: http calls in angular2 are expecting an observable...so if you do this `http.get('https://www.google.com').subscribe(data => {console.log('response data:',JSON.stringify(data));},error => console.log(error))` you will see activity...I just tried in one of my test plunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because http.get() method returns an [Observable](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) and does not make the request until the data is needed (a kind of lazy-loading). As the task is executed asynchronously, you can subscribe to this:

```
http.get('https://www.google.com').subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

or convert to a Promise with which you may be familiar:

```
http.get('https://www.google.com').toPromise().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Now you can notice that in the both cases from above the request was made.